# Binding jtable from mysql database in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, vector, jtable

I have almost finished my project and I'm getting stuck with displaying the Data from my DB into a Jtable. I have searched and read and still can't get this to work. I'm not displaying any errors but when I run the code I get an error when I click on search for the data. I get

```
java.sql.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "INVENTORY"
```

at line 1, column 9. Does that mean my code is fine and its a problem with my Database?

Here is my code.

```
private void cmdSEARCHINVActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

  ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/The_Home_Place";
        String uName = "Lynn";
        String uPass = "Lynn";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String Query = "SELECT *INVENTORY";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rs.getMetaData();
        int col = rsmt.getColumnCount();
        Vector column = new Vector(col);
        for(int i = 1; i <= col; i++)
        {
            column.add(rsmt.getColumnName(i));  
        }

        Vector data = new Vector();
        Vector row = new Vector();
        while (rs.next());
        {
            row = new Vector(col);
            for(int i = 1; i <= col; i++){
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        //Create the Table

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,120);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTable table = new JTable(data,column);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(jsp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
             }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query has invalid syntax. Try changing it to

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY";
```

instead. Also, you shouldn't be using `Vector` anymore, because the class is obsolete; use an `ArrayList<String>` (a [generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) collection, not a raw one) for storing the row data instead.

Comment: fixed the SQl query and updated my class from Vector to ArrayList. Now I'm getting an error where i create my table. Im not sure if i still need to create my variable col or nott

Comment: Ok im confused on how i need to implement this ArrayList with the generic collection

Comment: Well, technically the code should work with raw `Vector`s, as well. It's just obsolete syntax. The only thing that was clearly broken was the DB query.

Comment: When running the code with Vector it runs. But when i click the search button i get says "Invalid Operation at current cursor position"

Comment: Where is the error coming from? You should add `ex.printStackTrace();` into the `catch` block for making debugging simpler.

Comment: Yea its throwing a bunch of errors.java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
 at Client.Customer.cmdSEARCHINVActionPerformed(Customer.java:893)
 at Client.Customer.access$600(Customer.java:10)
 at Client.Customer$7.actionPerformed(Customer.java:458)

Comment: I dont know if that helps you or not